# How to adjust the density of global divergent wind vector using quiver

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, python-xarray

I plotted the divergent wind vector globally using `cartopy` and `quiver` in `PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)` projection.

```
lat=lats.to_numpy()
lon=lons.to_numpy()
uchi_1=uchi1.to_numpy()
vchi_1=vchi1.to_numpy()

ax2 = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180))
q2=ax2.quiver(lon, lat, uchi_1, vchi_1,width=0.0009, scale_units='xy',scale=0.05,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
qk2=plt.quiverkey (q2,0.96, 0.88, 1, '1 m/s')

ax2.coastlines()
ax2.set_xticks([0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 359.99], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax2.set_yticks([-90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
lon_formatter = LongitudeFormatter(zero_direction_label=True,number_format='.0f')
lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter()
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
plt.title('Divergent wind', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
```

The plot is showing as:
[image: Divergent wind vector plot]

I want to reduce the density of wind vector. I tried skipping some values as

```
q2=ax2.quiver(lon[::3], lat[::3], uchi_1[::3], vchi_1[::3],width=0.0009, scale_units='xy',scale=0.05,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

But it is showing error -

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [35], in <cell line: 7>()
      4 vchi_1=vchi1.to_numpy()
      6 ax2 = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180))
----> 7 q2=ax2.quiver(lon[::3], lat[::3], uchi_1[::3], vchi_1[::3],width=0.0009, scale_units='xy',scale=0.05,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
      8 qk2=plt.quiverkey (q2,0.96, 0.88, 1, '1 m/s')
     10 ax2.coastlines()

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py:310, in _add_transform.<locals>.wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    305     raise ValueError('Invalid transform: Spherical {} '
    306                      'is not supported - consider using '
    307                      'PlateCarree/RotatedPole.'.format(func.__name__))
    309 kwargs['transform'] = transform
--> 310 return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py:1841, in GeoAxes.quiver(self, x, y, u, v, *args, **kwargs)
   1839     if (x.ndim == 1 and y.ndim == 1) and (x.shape != u.shape):
   1840         x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
-> 1841     u, v = self.projection.transform_vectors(t, x, y, u, v)
   1842 return matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver(self, x, y, u, v, *args, **kwargs)

File lib/cartopy/_crs.pyx:509, in cartopy._crs.CRS.transform_vectors()

ValueError: x, y, u and v arrays must be the same shape
```

Anyone please help.

**Edit_1**
I'm new to python programming. I used u wind and v wind netCDF data file format.
https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis.derived/pressure/uwnd.mon.mean.nc
https://downloads.psl.noaa.gov/Datasets/ncep.reanalysis.derived/pressure/vwnd.mon.mean.nc
Minimal Reproducible Code-

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LongitudeFormatter, LatitudeFormatter

ds1 = xr.open_dataset('Downloads/uwnd.mon.mean 1948-2022.nc')
ds2 = xr.open_dataset('Downloads/vwnd.mon.mean 1948-2022.nc')
lon = ds1['lon'][:]  
lat = ds1['lat'][:] 
u = ds1['uwnd']
u
# At 850 hPa leval
u_850= u[0,2,:,:]
u_850 
v = ds2['vwnd']
v
# At 850 hPa level 
v_850= v[0,2,:,:]
v_850
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180))
q=ax.quiver(lon.to_numpy()[::3], lat.to_numpy()[::3], u_850.to_numpy()[::3], v_850.to_numpy()[::3],width=0.00095,scale_units='xy' ,scale=3,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())#scale_units='xy'
qk=plt.quiverkey (q,0.96, 1.02, 0.1, '0.1 m/s')
ax.coastlines()
ax.set_xticks([0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300, 359.99], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_yticks([-90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
lon_formatter = LongitudeFormatter(zero_direction_label=True,number_format='.0f')
lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lon_formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you checked the shape of x, y, u and v? What is the output? The error message is quite clear. For a concrete solution provide a [mre].

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny, I made a minimal reproducible example. Please see the EDIT_1 section of my question. Actually I'm new to python and I'm not able to figure out how to resolve this issue.

Comment: you passed 4 arrays to quiver(): `lon[::3], lat[::3], uchi_1[::3], vchi_1[::3]`. you should look up the doc to identify which one is `x`, `y`, `u`, `v`. then make sure they all have the same shape (ie, compare output of `print(x.shape)`, `print(u.shape)` and `print(v.shape)`)

Comment: @AcaNg, as you suggested I checked the shape ```print(lon[::3].shape)```  it is (48,) and ```print(lat[::3].shape)``` is (25,), ```u[::3]``` shape is (25,144), It was 2D and I was skipping only one dimension. So the mistake was here.  ```q2=ax2.quiver(lon[::3], lat[::3], uchi_1[::3,::3], vchi_1[::3,::3])``` . This is working perfectly fine now. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you figured out how to get this up and running by downsampling the 2D arrays in comments! I just wanted to offer an xarray-native way of approaching this, as it provides a pretty powerful and friendly way of interacting with large labeled datasets like this.

As of v0.17.0 (Feb 2021), xarray has a [`xr.Dataset.plot.quiver()`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.plot.quiver.html) method. This is also covered in the [dataset plotting methods docs](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/plotting.html#quiver).

To make use of these methods, start by combining your data into a single Dataset. You could do this with the data you already loaded using [`xr.merge`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.merge.html), e.g. `ds = xr.merge([ds1, ds2])`, or by opening them with [`xr.open_mfdataset`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.open_mfdataset.html), e.g.:

```py
In [3]: ds = xr.open_mfdataset(local_fps)

In [4]: ds
Out[4]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (level: 17, lat: 73, lon: 144, time: 893)
Coordinates:
  * level    (level) float32 1e+03 925.0 850.0 700.0 ... 50.0 30.0 20.0 10.0
  * lat      (lat) float32 90.0 87.5 85.0 82.5 80.0 ... -82.5 -85.0 -87.5 -90.0
  * lon      (lon) float32 0.0 2.5 5.0 7.5 10.0 ... 350.0 352.5 355.0 357.5
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 1948-01-01 1948-02-01 ... 2022-05-01
Data variables:
    uwnd     (time, level, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(893, 17, 73, 144), meta=np.ndarray>
    vwnd     (time, level, lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(893, 17, 73, 144), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes:
    title:          monthly mean u wind from the NCEP Reanalysis
    description:    Data from NCEP initialized reanalysis (4x/day).  These ar...
    platform:       Model
    Conventions:    COARDS
    NCO:            20121012
    history:        Mon Jul  5 22:36:33 1999: ncrcat uwnd.mon.mean.nc /Datase...
    dataset_title:  NCEP-NCAR Reanalysis 1
    References:     http://www.psl.noaa.gov/data/gridded/data.ncep.reanalysis...
```

You can use the selection methods [`.sel`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.Dataset.sel.html) and [`.isel`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/latest/generated/xarray.Dataset.isel.html) to select slices by label and position, respectively:

```py
In [5]: first_timestep_850 = ds.sel(level=850).isel(time=0)

In [6]: first_timestep_850
Out[6]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 73, lon: 144)
Coordinates:
    level    float32 850.0
  * lat      (lat) float32 90.0 87.5 85.0 82.5 80.0 ... -82.5 -85.0 -87.5 -90.0
  * lon      (lon) float32 0.0 2.5 5.0 7.5 10.0 ... 350.0 352.5 355.0 357.5
    time     datetime64[ns] 1948-01-01
Data variables:
    uwnd     (lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(73, 144), meta=np.ndarray>
    vwnd     (lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(73, 144), meta=np.ndarray>
Attributes:
    title:          monthly mean u wind from the NCEP Reanalysis
    description:    Data from NCEP initialized reanalysis (4x/day).  These ar...
    platform:       Model
    Conventions:    COARDS
    NCO:            20121012
    history:        Mon Jul  5 22:36:33 1999: ncrcat uwnd.mon.mean.nc /Datase...
    dataset_title:  NCEP-NCAR Reanalysis 1
    References:     http://www.psl.noaa.gov/data/gridded/data.ncep.reanalysis...
```

Now, we can use [`ds.plot.quiver`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.plot.quiver.html) and pass in the names of the `x, y, u, v` variables/coordinates:

```py
In [7]: fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)})
   ...: first_timestep_850.plot.quiver("lon", "lat", "uwnd", "vwnd", ax=ax)
   ...: ax.coastlines()
```

[image: map with dense quivers indicating windspeed and direction]

This can be downsampled similarly to your solution in comments. In xarray, selection/slicing is best done by dimension *name*, so we can use the following syntax to select every third value along lat/lon. `slice(None, None, 3)` is equivalent to `::3` (but can be passed in as a keyword argument):

```py
In [10]: fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)})
    ...: first_timestep_850.sel(lon=slice(None, None, 3), lat=slice(None, None, 3)).plot.quiver("lon", "lat", "uwnd", "vwnd", ax=ax)
    ...: ax.coastlines()
```

[image: map with downsampled quivers]

Alternatively, you could also [coarsen](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.coarsen.html) the data, allowing you to summarize the data spatially using a reduction like `mean`, `max`, etc.:

```py
In [12]: fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)})
    ...: first_timestep_850.coarsen(lat=3, lon=3, boundary='trim').mean().plot.quiver("lon", "lat", "uwnd", "vwnd", ax=ax)
    ...: ax.coastlines()
```

[image: map with quivers displaying the coarsened mean over lat and lon]

Note that you can still do all the extra matplotlib formatting you'd like on the `ax` object in each of these cases - I just skipped the extra steps to keep the walkthrough simple.

See the xarray docs on [indexing and selecting data](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/indexing.html), [coarsening large arrays](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/computation.html#coarsen-large-arrays), and [plotting](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/plotting.html) for more info.